# django-gcm under lighttpd/fastcgi?

Tags: django, fastcgi, lighttpd, google-cloud-messaging

Has anyone gotten the django-gcm server running under lighttpd using fastcgi?

I know how to get a general django application running under lighttpd/fastcgi, but I haven't been able to find instructions specifically for running the django-gcm server in this environment.

I've been trying various things and searching for examples, but so far, I have come up empty-handed.

Thanks for any pointers to docs or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Django-gcm is reusable application like others. Just create new django project and add 'gcm' to your INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py file. Btw in django-gcm package you have example of server application which you can simply run under lighttpd/fastcgi.